# Error importing mapbox packages into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to import the basic mapbox packages into Android Studio, but it isnt recognised it. Can someone help me?

```
import com.mapbox.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.maps.Style;
```

> Cannot resolve symbol 'mapbox'

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and configure it first.
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/

Comment: id just make these